# steady clock on ios that ignores sleep/suspended time

Tags: c++, ios, time

Could someone help me figure out what clock I can use on iOS in c++ to get a steady/monotonic class that doesn't tick if the app is suspended? I'm trying to measure an approximate time it takes to process something but a regular clock doesn't help since it can inflate times by including time when the app was suspended and doing nothing.

Something equivalent to the QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime on Windows.

mach_absolute_time doesn't tick if the iphone is suspended, but I want a clock that stops ticking if the app is suspended.

Comment: I don’t believe that there is such a clock. The typical approach is to save the `Date` when `didEnterBackground` is called